# What does "Vorderschienen" and "Erhebungen" in this sentence about beetles mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Isa wies auf das fünfzackige Kopfschild sowie auf die obersten Erhebungen der fingerförmig gezahnten Vorderschienen des Käfers.

I can’t find a definition for Vorderschienen. I’m also a bit fuzzy on Erhebungen but I think it means “protrusion” in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sentence is about biology, to be more precise about beetles ("Käfer").
The term "Vorderschiene" (Plural "Vorderschienen") refers to the lower part of the front leg (Tibia). I found two articles on Wikipedia on that topic, [one in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod_leg), the [other one in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insektenbein).
For humans, the part of the leg is called "Schienbein", but since beetles have six legs, the prefix "Vorder-" is added in order to denote the front leg.

In this case, the "Vorderschienen" are "fingerförmig gezahnt", which means "serrated in a finger shape".

Regarding "Erhebungen", I agree that "protrusion" fits quite well here. Since the context is a beetle, the protrusion is probably not too much. (Note that "Erhebung" could also mean "small mountain" if used in a geographical context).